# How to use service in angular2seed adavanced

Tags: firebase, angular2-seed

I am working on angular2seedadvanced with Firebase. While using Firebase service inside my component its not working. How can I use service inside the component in angular2seedadvanced. I am following

- https://github.com/jlooper/pocketrave
- https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/wiki/How-to-integrate-Firebase-across-all-platforms-(web-nativescript-desktop).

Here I attach my code files.

`firebase.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable, Inject, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { FIREBASE } from '../../demoapp/index';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseService {
private database: any;
private onSync: Function;
private userID: string;

constructor( @Inject(FIREBASE) firebase: any, private ngZone: NgZone) {
console.log('Constructing DatabaseService');
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  // your web config from Firebase console
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  storageBucket: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
this.database = firebase.database();
};

public authenticate() {

};
```

`login.component.ts`

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { BaseComponent } from '../../frameworks/core/index';
import { DatabaseService } from '../../frameworks/demoapp/services/database.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'demo-login',
providers: [DatabaseService],
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {

constructor(private databaseService: DatabaseService) {

}

login() {

this.databaseService.authenticate();
}
}
```

getting an error

> this.databaseService.authenticate is not a function.

What should I do? How can I solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the typings installed then the TypeScript transpiler will think it's an error.

Try adding a typings entry in your `typings.json` file for firebase:

`"firebase": "registry:dt/firebase#2.4.1+20160412125105",`

then open a console window and type `typings install`.

For reference:
https://github.com/ChuckkNorris/SkillPath/blob/master/typings.json